# Setting up cookie with Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

My js app is an advent calendar where users can open a 'door' on or before today's so the div background image changes.

I would like to set up a cookie so when they return the following day the divs still have the background image in place.

I have set up the cookie and door open code but I'm not sure how to integrate the cookie into the door open function.  Any help would be appreciated, many thanks.

Link to App: http://p3.katecooperuk.com

Door Open - select Random background image from Array:

```
$('.doors').click(function () {

    if (today.getMonth() !== 11) {

        return;
    }

    // Check if the date is tomorrow or later
    if (+($(this).attr('id').split('dec')[1]) > day) {

        // Show image telling user to come back
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(/images/come_back.png)');

        return;
    }

    // Otherwise it is today or earlier

    // Select Random Image
    var doorImage = getRandomImage(calendarImg);

    // Change background image of door that was clicked
    $(this).css('background-image', doorImage);

});
```

Cookie

```
//on document ready, checks if the cookie is set, and if so, sets the background with it's value
$(function(){
  if($.cookie('background-image') != null){
     $(this).css('background-image', $.cookie('background-image'));
  }
});

// Set cookie
$(function() {
  $(this).css('background-image', doorImage);
  $.cookie('background-image', doorImage);
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

`W3Schools` have a great newbie tutorial on cookies [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Basically, what you want to do is set the cookie value to the date it was created and whatever other parameters you want to set when the user comes back (such as the id's of the background images.) Then when the user enters your site you check to see if they have a cookie. If they do, check its date parameter. If it's not today (this is really easy to check with `JavaScript`) then use your extra parameters to set whatever background you want.

Make sure that whenever they change their backgrounds you reset your cookie data to the current backgrounds.

Hope this helps!

*

From you code, I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what it is you're trying to achieve. Also, I'm looking at your site and I don't see any saved cookies.. Try starting with a simple example, 1 door and 1 cookie. Then do a simple check to see if your cookie is working, for example, set a specific background when a cookie is detected and another if not. Once you successfully manage your cookie you can start making it more complex with more data in it.

Comment: Elad - many thanks for your advice, which I have tried to follow but it's still not working, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I'm very new to javascript - this is my first cookie attempt!  I've updated my code above

Comment: I've edited my original answer to better guide you in working with cookies.

Comment: If my answer got you on the right track to the solution, I'd appreciate marking it as the correct answer. If not, let me help! Thanks :)